# Hadoop cluster setup: Connection refused error

Tags: xml, hadoop

I have installed hadoop 2.8.5 and have completed the setup/configuration. I am trying to access HDFS and create directories top of DFS using cli.
I obtain the error:  localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException.

**Here is my core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/hadooptmpdata</value>
</property>
```

**Here is the hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

**Here is the mapreduce.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

**Here is yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>


<property>
    <name>mapreduceyarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

Output with jps command does not show namenode and datanode

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fs.defaultFS should be the namenode host's external IP or hostname, not 0.0.0.0

Seems like you haven't ran `start-dfs` script after formatting the namenode, then observed the logs for startup errors

You don't need datanodes to get started. Focus on just getting a healthy namenode.

Also, consider using Apache Ambari instead of manual installation

Comment: I did run start-dfs.sh beforehand. It starts both namenode and datanode without any errors. Also before giving 0.0.0.0 i gave localhost yet ended up with the same error. I noticed that though my namenode and datanode start, I am unable to connect to them hence why jps does not show it.

Comment: Okay then then you need to find the log files to figure out the issue

Comment: And again, the address should not be localhost/127.0.0.1 if you're expecting other machines to connect